# Obtener datos de un JSON y utilizar un valor como condición en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este Json que obtengo a partir de una consulta de MySql:

```
[
  {
    "contador": 8
  }
]
```

y el codigo javascript:

```
async function contador(){
    var url = URLSERVIDOR + 'contador'
    var respuesta = await fetch(url, {
        "method": 'GET',
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
        }
    })

    listado = await respuesta.json();

for (registro of listado) {
    var html = `<label>${registro.contador}</label>`
}

if (html >= 1){
    document.querySelector('#txtMsjError').innerHTML = "Encontrado"
}else{
    document.querySelector('#txtMsjError').innerHTML = "No encontrado"
}
}
```

independientemente del numero que me de Json, como en este caso, la respuesta siempre sera "No encontrado", somo si este fuera un 0, no logro que funcione correctamente.
O estoy usando mal la variable...

Comment: Ya que acá tienes una respuesta, elimina la otra pregunta que además está incompleta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]La solución a tu problema reside en que JavaScript no puede acceder a tu variable `html` ya que su declaración esta dentro del bucle for.

Declara la variable fuera del bucle for y definela dentro.

Por otro lado, no tiene sentido que compares la variable con un numero ya que estas dandole un string. Deberias verificar si la longitus de `listado` es mayor o igual a 1. Para ello, el prototipo Array tiene un miembro `length` el cual retorna un valor del tipo entero con el cual puedes comparar. Tambien tenemos que comparar que el primer `count` es mayor a 0, con lo cual verificamos tambien eso. Si quieres verificar todos los objetos que hay dentro del array, te recomiendo usar el metodo [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) de los Arrays. En este ejemplo no lo uso, lo tendrás que implementar tú.

Algo asi:

```js
async function contador(){
    const url = URLSERVIDOR + 'contador'
    const respuesta = await fetch(url, {
        "method": 'GET',
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
        }
    })

    let listado = await respuesta.json();

    let html;
    for (registro of listado) {
        html = `<label>${registro.contador}</label>`
    }

    if (listado.length > 0 && listado[0].count > 0){
        document.querySelector('#txtMsjError').innerHTML = "Encontrado"
    }else{
        document.querySelector('#txtMsjError').innerHTML = "No encontrado"
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo hice tal cual, pero ahora todos dicen que es Encontrado aun cuando el valor es 0

Comment: Ah si, fallo mio, deja lo corrijo

Comment: Ya lo corregí @Eduardo

Comment: ya lo probe pero no funciona, hay algo en esa condicion que no se cumple como deveria, pero en definitiva este camino parece mas logico

Comment: Verifica que la request se esté haciendo bien. Por otro lado, te recomendaria verificar que no te saltas ninguna barra lateral en la url.

Comment: @Eduardo revisa el contenido de listado para confirmar que sí recibes el resultado como lo esperas

Comment: ya verifique que la url funcione cada vez que hace la consulta me arroja el contador que corresponde. Quiero mencionar que literalmente la consulta que hago en MySql es sobre un contador COUNT y dependiendo del numero que me de, pues es la condicion. no se si eso sea relevante

Comment: Printea por consola la respuesta y verifica que esté todo bien

Comment: puse una imagen con dos consultas una que vale 0 y la otra que vale 8, hay algo aqui que haga que la condicion no funcione???

Comment: quiero compartir el error, la solicion aqui mencionada es la correcta solo habia un error de escritura en vez de ser count es contador lo verifique con un console.log, ahora por fin funciona como deberia